# Freemarker in Liferay List?has_content returns TRUE although list not exist or empty

Tags: list, liferay, freemarker

Depending on the existence of a list or the fact that this list is not empty I want to have a  shown or not. My code:

```
<#if EventPictures.getSiblings()?has_content> 
    <section class="more grid">
      <#list EventPictures.getSiblings() as cur_EventPictures>
        <#if cur_EventPictures.getData()?? && cur_EventPictures.getData() != "">
    <div class="more-content">
      <div class="strcontainer">
            ... Fill the content
        </div>
    </div>
    
        </#if>
    </#list>
  </section> 
</#if>
```

Even there is nothing in EventPictures, the section, including the divs, is still shown although there is no content. The Freemarker code is used in Liferay. Why is this not working?

Comment: Note related to your problem, but instead of `EventPictures.getSiblings()` and `cur_EventPictures.getData()`, etc. you should write `EventPictures.siblings` and `cur_EventPictures.data`, etc. Makes the template easier to read (and type).

Answer (score 2):

With the input of user7294900 I started realising that Liferay, based on the template always creates the list. If you did not enter anything in the list, It creates an list with 1 item. That item is empty. So list size is always 1 but can be empty. Checking the content of the list items does the job. I added one piece of code with an extra variable to make it happen.

```
    <#assign EventPicturesCount = "Empty">
    <#if EventPictures.getSiblings()?has_content>
    <#list EventPictures.getSiblings() as cur_EventPictures>
        <#if cur_EventPictures.getData()?? && cur_EventPictures.getData() == "">
        <#else>
            <#assign EventPicturesCount = "Filled">
        </#if>
    </#list>
    
</#if>
<#if EventPicturesCount ?? && EventPicturesCount != "Empty">
```

Now the section does only appear when the first listitem has content. I assume it can be shortened but as I am not an experienced user. I will have it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker's [has_content](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_has_content) doc suggest using `expr!?size > 0` instead

> Note that when your data-model implements multiple template model interfaces you may get unexpected results. However, when in doubt you can use always use expr!?size > 0 or expr!?length > 0 instead of expr?has_content

```
<#if (EventPictures.getSiblings()!?size > 0)>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using this expression gives an error saying that the #if statement expects a boolean but received a number... I assume indeed the template model is interfering. When I use a single variable with the "var.getdata ??" expression, it works within the template. But for the list, it does not work.

Comment: Did you tried `<#if (EventPictures.getSiblings()!?size > 0)>` ?

Comment: @Bongo Try `<#if (EventPictures.getSiblings()!?size &gt; 0)>`

Comment: Tried it and the error is gone. Thanks for the tip. But the main problem remains. It shows the section. So somewhere in the background the template creates a list although there is not anything in it.

Comment: If I do <#if (EventPictures.getSiblings()!?size > 1)>, The sections disappears when I have no list item or only 1. So the template always creates the list, and puts one listitem in it. The list item might be empty.